# How do I implement selective refresh with a customizer setting?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a section in a page template in the theme I'm making that displays content based on a page the user selects in the customizer using the dropdown-pages control. Right now it's just using the standard default refresh transport, but since that's kind of clunky reloading the whole iframe, I was wondering if it was possible to use the new selective refresh feature. But I'm not sure how to implement it. Anyone know if this is possible and if so how to do it?

Here is the code in my page template that displays the content:

```
<?php if ((get_theme_mod( 'intro_page' )) != '') {

$intro_id = get_theme_mod( 'intro_page' );

$intro_header = get_the_title( $intro_id );

$intro_excerpt = get_the_excerpt( $intro_id );

$intro_link = get_the_permalink( $intro_id );

$intro_linktext = get_post_meta( $intro_id, 'emm_cta_text', true );

echo '<h1>' . esc_html($intro_header) . '</h1>' . '<p>' . esc_html($intro_excerpt) . '</p>';

if( ! get_post_meta( $intro_id, 'emm_cta_text', true ) ) {
echo '<p><a class="cta" href="' . esc_url($intro_link) . '">Learn More</a></p>';
}else{
echo '<p><a class="cta" href="' . esc_url($intro_link) . '">' . esc_html($intro_linktext) . '</a></p>';
}
} ?>
```

Here is the code for the setting in customizer:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'intro_page' , array(
'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
) );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'intro_page', array(
'label'    => __( 'Page to use for intro section', 'veritas' ), 
'section'  => 'intro',
'settings' => 'intro_page',
'type'     => 'dropdown-pages',
'priority' => 1
) );
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Create a function to output the selectively refreshed template code

(I wrapped the HTML within `<div class="cta-wrap">` to make it easier to target this particular block of markup.)

```
function wpse247234_cta_block() {
    if ( ( get_theme_mod( 'intro_page' ) ) != '' ) {
        $intro_id       = get_theme_mod( 'intro_page' );
        $intro_header   = get_the_title( $intro_id );
        $intro_excerpt  = get_the_excerpt( $intro_id );
        $intro_link     = get_the_permalink( $intro_id );
        $intro_linktext = get_post_meta( $intro_id, 'emm_cta_text', true );

        echo '<div class="cta-wrap">';
            echo '<h1>' . esc_html( $intro_header ) . '</h1>' . '<p>' . esc_html( $intro_excerpt ) . '</p>';

            if ( ! get_post_meta( $intro_id, 'emm_cta_text', true ) ) {
                echo '<p><a class="cta" href="' . esc_url( $intro_link ) . '">Learn More</a></p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p><a class="cta" href="' . esc_url( $intro_link ) . '">' . esc_html( $intro_linktext ) . '</a></p>';
            }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Update your template with a call to the newly created function above:

```
wpse247234_cta_block();
```

### Set up the Customizer

```
function wpse247234_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {

    $wp_customize->add_section( 'intro', array (
            'title'    => __( 'intro', 'text-domain' ),
            'priority' => 999,
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'intro_page' , array(
            'sanitize_callback' => 'absint',
            'transport' => 'postMessage'
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( 'intro_page', array(
            'label'    => __( 'Page to use for intro section', 'text-domain' ), 
            'section'  => 'intro',
            'settings' => 'intro_page',
            'type'     => 'dropdown-pages',
            'priority' => 1
    ) );

    $wp_customize->selective_refresh->add_partial( 'intro_page', array(
        'selector'            => '.cta-wrap',
        'container_inclusive' => true,
        'render_callback'     => 'wpse247234_cta_block',
        'fallback_refresh'    => false, // Prevents refresh loop when document does not contain .cta-wrap selector. This should be fixed in WP 4.7.
    ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse247234_customize_register' );
```

### Styling the item as it's being refreshed

While the partial is refreshing, the affected element will have the class `customize-partial-refreshing` added to it. You can style it like so:

```
.cta-wrap.customize-partial-refreshing {
    // styles...
}
```

### Helpful links

- [Selective Refresh in the Customizer](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/02/16/selective-refresh-in-the-customizer/)
- [Theme Options – The Customizer API](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/customizer-api/)
- Taking a look at how [Twenty Sixteen v1.3](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentysixteen/) handles selective refresh was helpful in getting this example to up and running.

Comment: seems like you know too much ;) so if you think you might have an answer the next level is to have a mixed settings with some attribute change triggering partial refresh while others full refresh (full in this case is needed to set global JS options). Should I make a formal question? ;))

Comment: @MarkKaplun, if you knew how long this answer took me it wouldn't seem that way at all :-) In my testing setup, I have a mixture of full page refresh options in addition the selective refresh above. Seems to work fine right out of the box. If you don't mind I would prefer a new question with your specific details, and when time allows, I'd be happy to take a crack at it.

Comment: Regarding the `fallback_refresh` comment: “prevents constant refresh when document does not contain .cta-wrap selector”. The bug with infinite reloading should be fixed in 4.7-RC1.

Comment: @dave-romsey What's the point of the JS in `customize-preview.js`? It looks like it is setting the element's content to the page ID? Shouldn't selective refresh be handling all of this for you instead and so there is no need for this JS file at all?

Comment: @WestonRuter thank you for the note about the fix for the infinite refresh in 4.7-RC1. You are right (naturally :-p ) about the `customize-preview.js` being unnecessary too, so I've removed it from the answer.

Comment: Here it comes... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/247251/how-to-mix-partial-and-full-page-refresh-in-the-same-section-of-the-customizer

Comment: Nice demonstration,thanks @dave-romsey. PS: maybe it would be simpler here to just define a simple function as the `customize_register` action callback, instead of a class that's not used for anything else in the example?

Comment: Thank you, @birgire. Good point. I've replaced the class with a function.

Comment: @dave-romsey Cheers. Yeah, it can be useful retain the `customize-preview.js` JS instant live preview specifically in the case where it is possible to supply a low-fidelity preview while the high-fidelity selective refresh request is being made. This is done in the core themes for the site title and tagline, where JS applies the raw value instantly and then the selective refresh request returns with high fidelity preview, where the text has `wptexturize` and other filters applied. Here though it doesn't make sense, in any case.

Comment: @WestonRuter Thank you for stopping by and providing the explanation about the JS. I was wondering where that ID came from and you cleared that up for me too. Much appreciated!